# How to set non Table field of SQL into Crystal Report Design and Parameter

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, crystal-reports, desktop-application

I am fetching data by this query

```
select 
    employee.empcode, employee.fullname,
    count(attendance.Status) 
from 
    employee 
inner join 
    attendance on employee.empcode = attendance.EmpCode 
group by 
    employee.empcode, employee.fullname 
order by 
    employee.empcode
```

[image: Sql Result]

But (No Column Name) is not my SQL table's column - how to put it into Crystal Report Design and Code?

```
rptAttendance rpt = new rptAttendance();

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter myDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet myDS = new DataSet();

MyCommand.Connection = myConnection;
MyCommand.CommandText = "select employee.empcode, employee.fullname , COUNT(attendance.Status) from employee inner join attendance on employee.empcode = attendance.EmpCode group by employee.empcode, employee.fullname order by employee.empcode";
MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
myDA.Fill(myDS, "Attendance");
myDA.Fill(myDS, "Employee");

rpt.SetDataSource(myDS);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

[image: Report Design]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fc2m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss the name for the last column, try with:

```
select employee.empcode, employee.fullname , COUNT(attendance.Status) countColumn from employee inner join attendance on employee.empcode = attendance.EmpCode group by employee.empcode, employee.fullname order by employee.empcode
```

Edit: adding structure into report

i usually create a fake view like:

```
create view fakeView as
select convert(nvarchar(yourrealColumnLength) '') columnName,
       convert(int, 0) column2Name
       .......
```

then in the right panel inside crystal interface, just link your view to get a structure.

This could help you: [example](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/rpcry/using-crystal-reports-to-connect-to-a-data-sourc.html)

Comment: but how to add in designview of crystal Report ?

Comment: Just like any other column of that query

Comment: @MuhammadZohaib how did you do for the others? i usually did it by creating a fake view with column names and dataTypes and passing it in the report resource, i'll edit my answer with also this

Comment: @GuidoG sir there is no field in crystal report to add this

Comment: Naming your column as @claud.io here suggest should fix all. You can then add to your report just like you did all the other columns

Comment: @claud.io can you please provide a solution with screenshots

Comment: It does not matter if this column is a real column from your database or not, once its named in your `select` statement crystal will see it as a real column and you can use it just like all the other columns

Comment: @MuhammadZohaib  in Database Expert, select Create New Connection. In that look for OLE DB (ADO) data source. Once you open up the OLD DB provider you should see Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server, here choose the view  from your views to set the structure inside your report

Comment: @claud.io sir i add database tables in report but there is not field of my last column

Comment: @claud.io i add new picture

Comment: @MuhammadZohaib if you have only one structure to fill in your report, try to remove the not used structure that you've imported and add a new structure that is a fake view where you have the last column, when you link your query with the view loaded in the report you should see the last column

Comment: maybe i cant understand well. thank you so much sir you try to help

Comment: @MuhammadZohaib i'm sorry that i can't be clear, but i didn't have a machine with crystal atm so i can't give you screenshots or other stuff...

Comment: @claud.io you are absolutely correct my bro all done by your answer. thanks